# Capture all Domain requests when opening an url (online)

Tags: dns

Is there an online service which can list all DNS requests when opening an URL?

For example I input [www.myexternaldomain.com](http://www.myexternaldomain.com) and then it will list, that this website additionally loads googletagservices.com, gstatic.com, facebook.net, ...

In my current case, we have several ads blocked centrally via Cisco Umbrella Filter List and cannot open a specific website. But I cannot view at which point it is blocked. I need to find out which ad-website is necessary for executing the url.
In this case: [www.opodo.de](http://www.opodo.de)
But I guess there will be more cases later

To answer my initial question:
With the service urlscan.io I can accomplish that!

go to urlscan.io - input for example [www.opodo.de](http://www.opodo.de) and via "domain tree" I see all the linked domains that would be opened via links on the Website

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Several ad-blockers will not just list them, but completely stop them connecting. Apple's Safari will block all trackers by default too. Even fairly 'innocent' sites have tracking - https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZaIW.png

Comment: It works without all of these - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPHju.png - there are no actual off-site ads on that page.

Comment: opodo.de is blocked, when I block googletagservices.com
but how can I find out what is needed prior to that?

Comment: So I assume the attempt would be
- take a computer with unfiltered connection to the net
- use a browser with an adblocker
- check the adblocker, which additional sites/trackers are blocked

I had hoped there is an online service for that.

Comment: Well, empirically, blocking googletagservices doesn't prevent you getting to the site… as I just did it.

Comment: opodo.de was just an example - i could not unblock it, whatever I did, because I did not know, what was needed to unblock.
I set it to whitelist, so it works
but there will be future cases...

Answer (score 0):

Why use 3rd party service?

What about <kbd>F12</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> ( Developer console at whatever browser you're using ), then go to "network" tab and load the page.

You can also tick "Preserve log" if the address forwards you to whatever other website.

Comment: You are right - the Developer console might be useful (I do not use it so I did not think about it)
But there are two problems in this case:
  
- what if it is a malicious website? I do not want to load it for real, so a 3rd party service is better in such a case. Sandbox browser offsite  

- in this case, cisco umbrella prevents loading the website (because it blocks DNS) so it would not work. I would need to test it via an external network

Comment: @Dave It really depends on the use-case but I'm supporting Umbrella ( as an MSSP ) for two years, and I'm usually using a sandbox if the URL is suspicious. It is much more comfortable... Also, for business-matter, a free website might not suffice ( or might also follow you ) ... It really depends but it IS a better option for most cases IMHO